# Weld/CDI on Google App Engine - EventBus

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guava

CDI/Weld is really great, having features like

- `@Produces`
- `@Observes`

Solves already a lot of programming problems, especially on eventing. However CDI/Weld does not work with GAE, or at least that smoothly. So my question is, are  there any framework (that works with GAE) that solves the same eventing problems with Google App Engine